# Why can't a Scheme macro with the name "if" be defined?

Tags: macros, scheme, reserved-words, mit-scheme, syntax-rules

Here is a very simple Scheme macro that works, running on MIT/GNU Scheme 12.1:

```
1 ]=> (define-syntax example
        (syntax-rules () 
          ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: example

1 ]=> (example)

;Value: ok
```

However, defining the same macro with the name `if` gives an error:

```
1 ]=> (define-syntax if
        (syntax-rules () 
          ((_) 'ok)))

;Premature reference to reserved name: if
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

I've never used Scheme macros before, but I was under the impression that Scheme doesn't have "reserved" names and that any name in Scheme could be redefined. In fact, redefining `if` to a normal procedure works as expected:

```
1 ]=> (define (if) 'ok)

;Value: if

1 ]=> (if)

;Value: ok
```

I skimmed through the section on macros in the reference manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Macros.html), but I couldn't find the cause of the problem.

Is there something about the internal operation of `syntax-rules` that is causing this to fail?

**UPDATE 1**

Locally redefining `if` using `let-syntax` works:

```
1 ]=> (let-syntax ((if (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok))))
        (if))

;Value: ok
```

I'm still not sure why `define-syntax` doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**

It is possible to shadow other built-in keywords with macros:

```
1 ]=> (define-syntax define (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: define

1 ]=> (define)

;Value: ok

1 ]=> (define-syntax set! (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: set!

1 ]=> (set!)

;Value: ok

1 ]=> (define-syntax lambda (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: lambda

1 ]=> (lambda)

;Value: ok

1 ]=> (define-syntax cond (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: cond

1 ]=> (cond)

;Value: ok
```

Hilariously, you can even redefine `define-syntax`:

```
1 ]=> (define-syntax define-syntax (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Value: define-syntax

1 ]=> (define-syntax)

;Value: ok
```

However, attempting to redefine the keyword `syntax-rules` gets a similar error as for redefining `if` (note: I started a new REPL because the last macro shadowed `define-syntax`):

```
1 ]=> (define-syntax syntax-rules (syntax-rules () ((_) 'ok)))

;Premature reference to reserved name: syntax-rules
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

Comment: As it says, it's a reserved name. It's Scheme syntax, not something that can be customized.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think the issue is quite that simple. I was able to successfully redefine `if` using `let-syntax` (see the update I added just now), so Scheme allows redefining syntax like that to some extent.

Comment: The difference is that `let-syntax` is local, it doesn't try to modify the top-level binding, which is reserved.

Comment: Although that doesn't explain why you can redefine it as a function.

Comment: @Barmar I did some more experimenting (see Update 2). I was able to make a bunch of macros that shadow built-in syntax, including `define-syntax` itself. However, I got the same error as before if I try to name the macro `syntax-rules`.

Comment: Read the specification R7RS. `if` is syntax, not a macro. You can redefine macros, you can't redefine syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Which page are you looking at? I have a printout that I've been flipping through all afternoon. :)

Comment: p.13 4.1.5 Conditionals. `(if <test> <consequent> <alternate>) syntax`

Comment: The toplevel macro redefinition of `if` works in guile, chicken, gauche, chibi, chez, gambit and kawa, btw. And on MIT scheme 11.2.  (I might have too many Scheme implementations installed...)

Comment: The changelog for 12.1 says it has a complete rewrite of the `syntax-rules` implementation, which might have something to do with why it gives an error on that version but not the previous one I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` *can* be defined as a macro at the toplevel in many Scheme implementations. I tested

```lisp
 (define-syntax if
        (syntax-rules () 
          ((_) 'ok)))
(if) ; returns 'ok
```

on Guile 3.0.9, Chicken 5.3.0, Gauche 0.9.9, Chibi 0.10.0 (in the form of the latest from git), Chez 9.6.2, Gambit 4.9.5, Kawa 3.1.1, and MIT/GNU Scheme 11.2. All accepted and ran the code without errors. You said you're using MIT/GNU Scheme 12.1, so something that changed between the two versions is responsible.

Interestingly, the redefinition of `syntax-rules` gives the error in 11.2. Guile, Chicken, Gauche, Chibi, and Gambit all accepted it, while Chez and Kawa threw errors.

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a bug report to the MIT/GNU Scheme project.